# Downloading third party softwares in local repository using apt-mirror

Tags: repository, apt-mirror

Currently I have setup a local repository using `apt-mirror` to establish a offline local repository for Ubuntu 16.04.

However, only the official packages are downloaded. I would like to make the third party libraries like Google Chrome, OwnCloud etc. to be also available in my offline local repository.

What changes shpuld I make in the file `mirror.list` so that `apt-mirror` can do the job?

Comment: Doing what you did for the official mirrors with the Chrome/Owncload repos didn't work? It worked fine for me with Chrome, anyway.

Comment: @muru Installing directly from Internet worked for me too. But I wanted to include it in my offline local repository using apt-mirror!

Comment: I meant that mirroring Chrome repos worked fine for me, using Chrome's repo lines in the same format in `mirror.list`

Comment: If you compare the file with /etc/apt/sources.list, you will see that it's very similar. /etc/apt/mirror.list mainly lists the repositories that should be mirrored, plus a few other options.  See https://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror#-configure-aptmirror